# angularjs checking data before request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, request-cancelling

I'm sending data to my php script. Data looks like [image]

Controller:

```
app.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$q){
  $scope.search = function( values , type) {
    if($scope.abort) {
        $scope.abort.resolve();
    }
    $scope.abort = $q.defer();
    var data={};
    data.values=values;
    data.type=type;

    $http.post("search.php", data,{timeout:$scope.abort.promise}).then(function success (response) {

            $rootScope.search_result=response.data;
        },function error (response){
            console.log("Request cancelled");
        }
    );
  };
});
```

But I want to check if in at list one array item has property val!=""; Is there any way to check it besides cycle like

```
var flag=0;
for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    if(values[i].val!="") flag=1;
}
if(flag)$http...
```

?

Comment: Take a look at _.js. It has a lot of really useful options for querying arrays and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example) method

```
var flag = data.values.find(function(element){
     return element.val != ''
})

if(flag)$http...
```

Comment: this function returns the whole object of values array

Comment: yes, if you want find index use findIndex method `data.values.findIndex(`

Comment: Your answer helps me! Tnx u!) The problem was that my object at start don't have property val. So I write `return element.val != '' && element.val!=undefined`

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `values` array is in an object. So you should use `yourObjName.values` to access it.

Here is a demo:

```js
var myData = {
    type: 'find_company', 
    values: [
        {name: 'Rob', val: ''},
        {name: 'Jon', val: '1'},
        {name: 'Aria', val: ''},
        {name: 'Ned', val: '2'},
    ]
};

var flag = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < myData.values.length; i++) {
    if(myData.values[i].val != "") flag++;
}

if(flag) {
    /* $http.post */
    console.log('flag is:', flag);
}
```

Comment: yep, but this is what I'm talking about. I was hoping that there is another way to check if there is at list one object in array which has property val!=""

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var array = [{val:"",name:"lucas"},{val:"12",name:"jaque"},{val:"12",name:"celine"},{val:"sdfsdf",name:"bruno"},{val:"",name:"ugo"},{val:"",name:"json"}]

console.log(array.filter(x => x.val != ""));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a bit faster if you exit the loop the first time it matches

```js
var flag = false;
for(var i = 0; i < myData.values.length; i++) {
    if(myData.values[i].val != ""){ 
      flag=true;
      i = myData.values.length;
    }
}

if(flag)
{

}
```